# How do I convert a string containing a hexadecimal pair to a byte?

Tags: c#, string, byte, hex

I have a string containing a hexadecimal value. Now I need the content of this string containing the hexadecimal as a byte variable. How should I do this without changing the hexadecimal value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa-in-c

Comment: Not a duplicate (wrt C#) as far as I can tell. There are many variations, but this is specific ("xx" -> byte) and warrants a simpler answer than a number of the more complex scenarios.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An [alternative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k.aspx) to the options posted so far:

```
byte b = Convert.ToByte(text, 16);
```

Note that this will return 0 if `text` is null; that may or may not be the result you want.

Comment: Damn, i even looked at the `Convert.ToByte` method but totally didn't spot that overload which takes the base as parameter...

Answer (score 2):

If it is just a single byte in the string, you can do this:

```
        string s = "FF";
        byte b;


        if (byte.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out b))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(b.ToString());  //255
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String strHex = "ABCDEF";
Int32 nHex = Int32.Parse(strHex, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
Byte[] bHex = BitConverter.GetBytes(nHex);
```

I think that's what you're looking for. If not, post an update with a more explicit definition of what you're looking for.